# Schema evolution with Hadoop Avro in C#

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, schema, avro

**In short: How can I generate a JSON schema for multiple .Net assemblies, and still use strong type deserialization?**

We are using [Microsoft Avro](https://hadoopsdk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Avro%20Library) to serialize .Net (C#) objects between systems.

Because Avro is using sequential indices to keep references of types, and because we are using Reflection to serialize, every time we compile a new version, the type indices change.

Sender and receiver end up having different type indices, and they then end up deserializing for the wrong type; which means best case, we get an error, worst case, we get mismatching data.

Upgrading all systems at once is not possible.

The only way I see to avoid this problem is to use a Schema, but I cannot find 1) How to generate that schema using code (I don't want to manually create the schema), and 2) Keep using strong type when serializing/deserializing

I read through this: https://github.com/Azure/azure-content/blob/master/articles/hdinsight/hdinsight-dotnet-avro-serialization.md and I cannot find a way to achieve this... It seems to me that this should be a typical problem developers using Avro should have, so what am I missing?